# Timer.fire() not working after invalidating in Swift

Tags: swift, nstimer

After using

```
@IBAction func pauseButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    if isPaused == false {

        timer.invalidate()
        isPaused = true
        displayLabel.text = "\(count)"
        println("App is paused equals \(isPaused)")

    } else if isPaused == true {
        var isPaused = false
        timer.fire()
        //  timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("updateTime"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
}
```

to pause the app, i'd like to hit pause again, in which case, the timer will continue to count from where it left off.

Additionally, when i press pause/play too many times, multiple instances of the timer occur which will cause the timer to increase a few times per second.

Please help!

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Navigation Bars
//
//  Created by Alex Ngounou on 8/27/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Alex Ngounou. All rights reserved.
//


import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var timer = NSTimer()
    var count = 0
    var isPaused = false

    func updateTime() {

        switch count {
        case 0, 1:
            count++
        println( "\(count) second.")
        displayLabel.text = "\(count)"

        case 2:
            count++
            println("\(count) seconds.")
            displayLabel.text = "\(count)"

        default:
            count++
            println("\(count) seconds.")
            displayLabel.text = "\(count)"

        }
    }




    **strong text**@IBAction func playButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        var isPaused = false

         timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("updateTime"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }


    @IBAction func stopButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        timer.invalidate()
        count = 0
        displayLabel.text = "0"
    }


    // if it's currently paused, pressing on the pause button again should restart the counter from where it originally left off.

    @IBAction func pauseButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        if isPaused == false {

        timer.invalidate()
        isPaused = true
        displayLabel.text = "\(count)"
        println("App is paused equals \(isPaused)")

        } else if isPaused == true {

            var isPaused = false

            timer.fire()

            //  timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("updateTime"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }
    }


    @IBAction func resetButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        timer.invalidate()
        count = 0
        displayLabel.text = ""
    }


    @IBOutlet weak var displayLabel: UILabel!



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("updateTime"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: I realize that this is two problems in one, i can post them separately if need be. Please help!

Comment: yo should never compare a Bool type to true. it is redundant. Change if isPaused == false { .. } to if !isPaused { .. }. Change if isPaused == true { .. } to if isPaused { .. }. You can also just toggle isPaused value adding a single line out of the if statement like this. isPaused = !isPaused

Comment: While I don't do it, there's nothing wrong with comparing bool to true/false if it helps readability.  What is incorrect however, is the local declaring of " var isPaused = false" inside the else if of the paused button action.  This isn't changing the global isPaused... but creating a another variable with a more limited scope and setting that to false, then destroying it when the else if is completed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/

> Once invalidated, timer objects cannot be reused.

So essentially an `NSTimer` will do nothing at all once invalidated. Your `timer` property must be assigned to a newly constructed `NSTimer` object after that point to get it to fire again. If your invalidation bookkeeping is accurate, there is no "buildup" problem of multiple timers.

Probably the easiest method to your actual problem, though, is logical filtering. That is, keep the `NSTimer` object around indefinitely and let it fire continually. When the stored property `isPaused` is `true`, you ignore timer events (by returning immediately from the processing function), otherwise you process them.

Comment: Wow! I'm more blown away by the fact that i can actually understand what you're saying, pats self on back. I'll definitely try out that approach!

Answer (score 1):

a "lazier" approach can be otherwise useful:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var timer: Timer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        startTimer()
    }


    final func killTimer(){
        self.timer?.invalidate()
        self.timer = nil
    }


    final private func startTimer() {

        // make it re-entrant:
        // if timer is running, kill it and start from scratch
        self.killTimer()
        let fire = Date().addingTimeInterval(1)
        let deltaT : TimeInterval = 1.0

        self.timer = Timer(fire: fire, interval: deltaT, repeats: true, block: { (t: Timer) in

            print("hello")

        })

    RunLoop.main.add(self.timer!, forMode: RunLoopMode.commonModes)

    }
```

Comment: I've been looking for an answer to my problem for hours and this is exactly what I was looking for.  This solved my problem exactly.  I'm afraid I don't understand what this is exactly doing though.  

What may I ask is the "RunLoop" portion about?

Answer (score -2):

Declare your timer as 'weak var' like this:

```
weak var timer: Timer?
```

Comment: Please add some more explanation to your code such that others can learn from it